# I got TradingView's 'end of line without continuation' error with Pine Script

Tags: pine-script

I am using this code in Pine Script but getting the *"mismatched input 'a' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'"* error.

How to fix that error with this function code?

```
val(s) =>
     if s != s[1] 
     a = s-s[1]
     if s = s[1]
     a
    a
```

Answer (score 11):

The ['end of line without continuation' error](https://kodify.net/tradingview/errors/end-line-without-continuation/) happens when there's an indentation mistake in the TradingView Pine code.

Looking at your code (and assuming copying it into StackOverflow went right), there is indeed an indentation problem:

```
val(s) =>
     if s != s[1] 
     a = s-s[1]
     if s = s[1]
     a
    a
```

There are two indentation problems in this code:

- The first 4 lines of the function are indented with 5 spaces (or 1 Tab plus a space). But code lines of a function need to be indented with 4 spaces (or 1 Tab) in TradingView Pine.
- The two lines that follow after the if statements are not indented. But they do need to be: with 4 spaces (or 1 Tab) or a multiple thereof.

When we fix those two points the code becomes:

```
val(s) =>
    if s != s[1] 
        a = s-s[1]
    if s == s[1]
        a
    a
```

(Note that I also replaced the `=` assignment operator with the `==` operator for equality here.)

---

The above code also triggers the ['undeclared identifier' error](https://kodify.net/tradingview/errors/undeclared-identifier/) because of the `a` variable: it is used *before* it is declared in your function. I wasn't sure if you also wanted that fixed or that the function code you posted is just part of a bigger function.

But if you also want to fix that 'undeclared identifier' error you'd change the function code to:

```
val(s) =>
    a = 0.0
    if s != s[1] 
        a := s-s[1]
    if s == s[1]
        a
    a
```

Comment: hi dear, I got 0 once s == s[1] so I can get the last value of a when s != s[1]