# syntax error input "end of line without line continuation"

Tags: pine-script-v5

```
TDUp = TD - ta.valuewhen(TD < TD[1], TD, 1 )
plotshape(TDUp==7?true:na,style=shape.triangledown, color=color.red, 
text="7",
textcolor=color.red, location=location.abovebar)
plotshape(TDUp==8?true:na,style=shape.triangledown, color=color.red, 
text="8",
textcolor=color.red, location=location.abovebar)
```

Says syntax error at line 6 which is the 1st photshape word

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I got TradingView's 'end of line without continuation' error with Pine Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51724359/i-got-tradingviews-end-of-line-without-continuation-error-with-pine-script)

Answer (score 0):

add spaces after using second line in code

```
TDUp = TD - ta.valuewhen(TD < TD[1], TD, 1 )
plotshape(TDUp==7?true:na,style=shape.triangledown, color=color.red, 
 text="7",
 textcolor=color.red, location=location.abovebar)
plotshape(TDUp==8?true:na,style=shape.triangledown, color=color.red, 
 text="8",
 textcolor=color.red, location=location.abovebar)
```